# Convert a string into an integer array

Tags: c#

Here is my string with 3 integers and I want to store it in 3 integer variables but I am unable to find an answer.

```
string orders = "Total orders are 2222 open orders are 1233 closed are 222";
```

This is what I want to do.

```
int total = 2222;
int close = 222;
int open = 1233;
```

Comment: Is the string fixed, will it be always "Total orders are ### open orders are ### .... " ?

Answer (score 5):

Try using *regular expressions* (to extract patterns) and *Linq* (to organize them into `int[]`):

```
  string orders = "Total orders are 2222 open orders are 1233 closed are 222";

  int[] result = Regex
    .Matches(orders, "[0-9]+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using only Linq:

```
int[] result =  orders
  .Split(' ')
  .Where(s => s
     .ToCharArray()
     .All(c => Char.IsDigit(c)))
  .Select(s => Int32.Parse(s))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: I suggest adding `Select` and `ToArray`, since question requires for *integer array*

Comment: Thx. I edited the answer

Comment: Be careful with `Char.IsDigit`, e.g. `Char.IsDigit('۶');` returns `true`; and `int.Parse("۶")` will *throw exception*; more accurate test is `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`

Comment: @Dmitry: Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
namespace StringToIntConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string orders = "Total orders are 2222 open orders are 1233 closed are 222";
            string[] arr = orders.Split(' ');
            List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
            foreach(string aString in arr.AsEnumerable())
            {
                int correctedValue ;
                if(int.TryParse(aString,out correctedValue))
                {
                    integerList.Add(correctedValue);
                }
            }

            foreach (int aValue in integerList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aValue);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect each character in turn and see if it is a numeric value:

```
string orders = "Total orders are 2222 open orders are 1233 closed are 222";

List<int> nums = new List<int>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Char c in orders)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        //append to the stringbuilder if we find a numeric char
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    else
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            nums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString()));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
}

if (sb.Length > 0)
{
    nums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString()));
}

//nums now contains a list of the integers in the string
foreach (int num in nums)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Output:

```
2222
1233
222
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
var intArr = 
    orders.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None)
          .Select(q =>
                  {
                      int res;
                      if (!Int32.TryParse(q, out res))
                          return (int?)null;
                      return res;
                  }).Where(q => q.HasValue).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the integers from the string:

```
var numbers =
    Regex.Split(orders, @"\D+")
        .Where(x => x != string.Empty)
        .Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Output

```
numbers[0] == 2222
numbers[1] == 1233
numbers[2] == 222
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] results =  orders.Split(' ').Where(s => s.ToCharArray().All(c => Char.IsDigit(c)))
    .Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```